# Adjoint derivative operator $R_2[x]$

Tags: linear-algebra

"Defining inner product in  $R_2[x]$ as $<f,g>= \int_0^1f(x)g(x)dx$. Let $D$ be the derivative operator $D:R_2[x]\rightarrow R_2[x]$. Find $D^*$."

So  the orthonormal basis of  $R_2[x]$ is $c=(1,\sqrt12(x-0.5),\sqrt180(x^2-x+\frac{1}{6}))$
   I understand that $[D^*]_c = ([D]_c)^*$ = 
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \sqrt12 & y & 0 \\
        0 & 2\sqrt15 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

In order to  get $D^*$ i tried to find the presentation of $D^*$ with respect to ths standard basis using the known algorithm which says that $D^*$ is the matrix whose  columns are the coordinates vectors with respect to E (standard basis) of the images of Basis C's vectors. It doesn't work. I'll be grateful if you could show me the solution using the algorithm that I have mentioned.

$D^*(ax^2 + bx + c) = 30(a + b)x^2 +(−26a − 24b + 12c)x + (3a + 2b − 6c)$